# Python - str() function completely alters list

Tags: python, string, list

Below is a code to generate the products of any two 3-digits numbers

```
integers_list = [(i * x)    for i in range(100,1000)   for x in range(100,1000)]
string_list = (map(str, integers_list))

integers_list.sort()
string_list.sort()

print integers_list[-10:-1]
print string_list[-10:-1]
```

gives:

```
[995004, 995004, 995006, 995006, 996003, 996003, 996004, 997002, 997002]
['99994', '99994', '99996', '99996', '99997', '99997', '99999', '99999', '99999']
```

This also occurs if I instead use `str(i * x)` in the list comprehension.

The numbers in the strings list aren't even possible given the expression.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: *Which* numbers in the strings list aren't possible given the expression? I only checked some of them, but 99999 for example can be factored into 3^2×41×271 = 369×271 which appears to match the list comprehension.

Comment: `'99999'` shouldn't be appearing 3 times; it's not a perfect square, and any number that isn't a perfect square should appear an even number of times.

Comment: Your output numbers would range from `10000` (5 digits) all the way through to `998001` (6 digits), so the numbers produced are perfectly plausible.

Comment: @user2357112: '99999' appears 4 times, but you sliced of the 4th occurrence. Remove the `-1` from your slices.

Comment: Ah, missed the `-1` ending index. Looks fine, then. (Also, I'm not the OP. Maybe I should change my user name. It seems such a pity to change it when I drew a number so close to the sequence of the first few primes...)

Comment: OP here, - thanks for the timely responses!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Ransom pointed out, the reason is because sorting strings is done lexicographically. To make the sorting process sort by integer value, do this:

```
string_list.sort(key=int)
integers_list.sort(key=int)
```

Answer (score 7):

Strings sort in a different order than integers. 9800 is greater than 990, but '9800' is less than '990'.

Comment: Lexicographic sorting for the win! Not sure why my copy-paste didn't work as expected at first. I probably forgot to sort.